# Test case for the magic-8-ball game

Tags: python, python-3.x, tdd

I'm mew to python and to TDD in general, I have developed a magic-8-ball game and I would like to learn how I can write the Test case for this program. The test should ensure the following:

- Allow the user to input their question
- Show an in progress message
- Create 10/20 responses and show a random response
- Allow the user to ask another question/advice or quit the game.

Below is my code. I know I should write Tests first but like I said, this a new territory for me.

```
RESPONSES =  ("It is certain", "It is decidedly so", "Without a doubt", "Yes-definitely",
 "You may rely on it", "As I see it, yes", "Most likely", "Outlook good", "Yes", 
 "Signs point to yes", "Reply is hazy", "Ask again later", "Better not tell you now",
  "Cannot predict now", "Concentrate and ask again", "Don't count on it", 
  " My reply is no", "My sources say no", "Outlook not so good", "Very doubtful")

from time import sleep
from random import choice
class MagicBall:
   def input_question(self):
        play_again = 'yes'
        while play_again == 'yes':
            str(input('Enter your question: '))
            for i in range(3):
                print("Loading {}".format(".."*i))
                sleep(1)
            print(choice(RESPONSES))
            play_again = str(input("Would you like to ask another question? yes/no ")).lower()
            if play_again == 'no':
                print("Goodbye! Thanks for playing!")
                SystemExit()
magic = MagicBall()
magic.input_question()
```

Comment: I'm unsure what your question is. If you're doing TDD and you've not written the test, are you asking us to write it for you?

Comment: Few improvements: 1) creating a class like that is, in my opinion, OOP abusing. You dont need a class and its object just to do some statements in python. 2) str(input()) is not necessary, for the input returns object of str type by itself (just write input()). 3) instead of "Loading {}". format (".." * i) use print("Loading", ".." * i) (print will automatically separate its parameters with whitespace)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unit tests are written to confirm that the expected output is obtained from a range of inputs for any function or method that carries out some computations and returns a value.

If you had a function to calculate the sum of two number:

```
def calc(first,second):
    return first + second
```

To confirm that the correct result is obtained you would do the following:

```
self.assertEqual(calc(5,5), 10)
```

You expect 10 to be the result from 5 and 5 so if it is something else it will produce an error.

I have also noticed this is a question from the Andela Interview questions scheduled for next week. Please review the documentation you were given for more clarity on how to write tests for different cases.